# Detect if "MediaElementAudioSource outputs zeroes due to CORS access restrictions for http..."

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, firefox, web-audio-api

While using Web Audio API I have this message in Firefox console

> The HTMLMediaElement passed to createMediaElementSource has a cross-origin resource, the node will output silence.

and in the same case that one in Chrome console

> MediaElementAudioSource outputs zeroes due to CORS access restrictions for http...

I get it. My question is: How can I detect such restrictions for audio/video html element from JavaScript code stand point? I do like to catch it before "createMediaElementSource" is called to prevent silencing audio.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
function _reallyPlayAudioURL(url)
{
    //...stuff
    // createMediaElementSource...
    //...etcetera
}
playAudioURL(url)
{
    if ( ! url) return;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("HEAD", url);
    xhr.onload = (_) => { _reallyPlayAudioURL(url); }
    xhr.onerror = (_) => { var msg
             = "Can't play audio for either or both of the following reasons:\n"
        msg += "  1) the file does not exist, it is damaged, unrecognized, etc.\n"
        msg += "  2) your browser is outputting silence pursuant to its CORS policy.\n\n";
        msg += "Please take the following precautions:\n"
        msg += "  1) ensure that audio file exists undamaged.\n"
        msg += "  2) restart your browser with the\n";
        msg += "       --allow-file-access-to-files\n";
        msg += "     switch on the command line.";
        alert(msg);
    }
    xhr.send();
}
```